# Breakpoints with constant intercept

Tags: r, breakpoints, linear-regression

I'm trying to find a structural break in my time series using the `breakpoints()` function (in the `strucchange` package). My goal is to find where is "knot" in my dataset. I'm looking for a procedure which would test all possible knots and choose the one who minimize an information criterion such AIC or BIC. `breakpoints()` does a good job but I would like to draw a continuous piecewise linear function. This, I would like the intercept to be the same before and after the breakpoint. Is anyone aware of a function or an option to do this ?

On the picture below, the red line is the true model and the blue line is fitted using `breakpoints()`. I would like a procedure which would fit the true model (no jump at the breakpoint).

See my [gist file](https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/6132114) to reproduce this example.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: In addition to not including `require(strucchange)` which I assume is where you are getting `breakpoints` in your code, you also have a function `ymd` that is not loaded.

Comment: @DWin, Thanks, the gist file has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'strucchange' package seems designed to return discontinuous results. You may want to look at packages that are designed the way you imagine the result to be structured. The 'segmented' package is one such.

```
require(segmented)
out.lm<-lm(y~date3,data=df)
o<-segmented(out.lm, seg.Z= ~date3, psi=list(date3=c(-10)),
     control=seg.control(display=FALSE))
 slope(o)
#$date3
#          Est. St.Err. t value CI(95%).l CI(95%).u
#slope1  0.3964  0.1802   2.199   0.03531    0.7574
#slope2 -1.6970  0.1802  -9.418  -2.05800   -1.3360

str(fitted(o))
# Named num [1:60] 1.94 2.34 2.74 3.13 3.53 ...
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:60] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
plot(y ~ date3, data=df)
lines(fitted(o) ~ date3, data=df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've got the following error message : `Error in segmented.lm(out.lm, seg.Z = ~date3, psi = list(date3 = c(-10)),  : 
  starting psi out of the admissible range`

Comment: Which date variable were you using?

Comment: I meant: of the three different date variables you constructed... which one were you using?

Comment: I would have expected it to error with date2. I don't really know what to say. I just re-ran that code and get no errors.

Comment: Now it works. I've change `psi=list(date3=c(-10))` to `psi=list(date3=c(10))`.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the full code : https://gist.github.com/blaquans/6133291. And it works !!

Comment: Is it possible to have more than on break ?

Comment: Yes. The example in `segmented` has two.

Comment: The peak appears to contain a separate segment here as well.

Answer (score 0):

A continuous piecewise linear fit is also called a linear spline, and can be fit with `bs` in the `splines` package (comes with base R).

```
lm(y ~ bs(x, deg=1, df, knots), ...)
```

The breakpoints are called knots, and you have to specify them via either the `knots` argument or the `df` argument (which chooses knots based on the quantiles of `x`).

You can also do it manually; linear splines are particularly simple to code up.

```
lm(y ~ x + pmax(0, x - k1) + pmax(0, x - k2), ...)
```

where `k1` and `k2` are the knots. Add more to taste.

Comment: To my knowledge, `bs()` doesn't find the knots which minimize an information criterion but take arbitrary knots such as quantiles of x. It doesn't tell me where exactly is the breakpoint.

Comment: Correct. But you didn't specify this in your question, did you? Might be an interesting exercise to write code to choose knots to minimise such a criterion....

Comment: You could probably just use the output from `breakpoints` to set the knot locations. You can see from your graph that it's actually detected the breakpoint quite accurately.

Comment: It's unclear to me if the knots would really be the same in a more complex dataset. I don't see any reason why it would be the case.